# How can I remove CantSplit from my TableRow in OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml

In our code-base we have an extension which adds the `CantSplit` property to every single `TableRow` in our document [CantSplit Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.cantsplit?view=openxml-2.8.1).

```
//pseudocode
var row = new TableRow();
var properties = new TableRowProperties();
properties.AppendChild(new CantSplit() { Val = OnOffOnlyValues.On });
row.AppendChild(properties);
```

The result is of course that table rows cannot split between pages. I tried several different methods of removing this property element:

- I tried commenting `TableRowProperties` out altogether such that there was no properties element appended to rows at all
- I tried commenting the `CantSplit` element, such that an empty `TableRowProperties` element is appended to every row

In both of these cases, the resulting word document appears corrupted and can't be opened.

I also tried setting `Val = OnOffOnlyValues.Off`, but this did not affect anything. The document was readable, but table rows still could not break across pages.

Comment: Are you sure that when adding the `CantSplit` element to the `TableRowProperties` element that it is in the correct position? In order for the WordProccesingMl to be correct, the elements have to be in a certain order as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablerowproperties?view=openxml-2.8.1)

Comment: @Discobarry It's the only property in the collection